# How to have different messages for FIRING and RESOLVED status in Prometheus Alertmanager?

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

Consider the following alerting template that creates alerts on all jobs in `.Values.jobs` and triggers an alert when a job with given `job_name` has not succeeded for a given interval:

```
{{- range $job, $value := .Values.jobs }}
- alert: Long Time Since Job Success ({{ $key }})
  expr: time() - max_over_time(max(mm_spark_succeeded{job_name="{{ $value.job_name }}"}) [168h:1m]) > 3600
  labels:
    severity: {{ $value.severity }}
    slack: {{ $value.slack }}
  annotations:
      format: verbose
      summary: "Long time since the job `{{ $job }}` was last successful."
      exclude_labels: k8sCluster,region,env,severity
{{- end }}
```

This triggers an alert and sends a slack message whenever the status of the alert is `FIRING` or `RESOLVED`.

In my use case, I want to show the annotations only when the status was `FIRING`. For `RESOLVED` status, I wish to show the alert but without the annotations (i.e. without summary message). How do I select/ignore annotations based on status of the alert?

I tried following but it didn't work:

```
{{- range $job, $value := .Values.jobs }}
- alert: Long Time Since Job Success ({{ $key }})
  expr: time() - max_over_time(max(mm_spark_succeeded{job_name="{{ $value.job_name }}"}) [168h:1m]) > 3600
  labels:
    severity: {{ $value.severity }}
    slack: {{ $value.slack }}
    {{- if eq .Status "firing"}}
      annotations:
          format: verbose
          summary: "Long time since the job `{{ $job }}` was last successful."
          exclude_labels: k8sCluster,region,env,severity
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

It throws an error: `eq: invalid type for comparison`